# Django Spreadsheet Form

Tags: mysql, django, forms

I have a form in Django that adds users to a mySQL database. However, the user will have to add tons of users, and some information will be copy and pasted. So I was thinking if there is a way to have a spreadsheet like form, where the column titles would be the fields that will be added to the database (such as id, firstname, lastname, etc...) and every row would be an information associated with one user. When you click the submit button, it will add each row to the database. Again, the user will need to have the ability to copy a row and paste it to another row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing is to get the users to use an actual spreadsheet and save it as CSV, then provide a facility to upload and process that CSV.

Comment: I'm trying to make the website do everything if its possible. That is a good back up plan though, thanks! I've been looking into handsontable, which is a javacript/css add on, do you think its possible to use this and find a way to make it behave like a form and add/modify data of a database?